# How to create multiple shapes on canvas on mouse drag and make them overlap?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Inside a `canvas` element, I want to be able to draw multiple rectangles on mouse drag (both left and right). So far I have the following:

```js
class Waveform {
  constructor(container_selector) {
    this.render(container_selector)
  }

  render(container_selector) {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector(container_selector)
    this.canvas.width = 800
    this.canvas.height = 150
    this.canvas.style.border = '1px solid black'
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7)'

    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown)
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove)
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp)
  }

  mouseDown = e => {
    this.drag = true
    this.rect = {}
    this.rect.x = e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft
    this.rect.y = 0
    this.rect.w = 1
    this.rect.h = this.canvas.height
    this.ctx.fillRect(
      this.rect.x,
      this.rect.y,
      this.rect.w,
      this.rect.h,
    )
  }

  mouseMove = e => {
    if (this.drag) {
      this.ctx.clearRect(this.rect.x, this.rect.y, this.rect.w, this.rect.h)
      this.rect.w = (e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft) - this.rect.x;
      this.ctx.fillRect(
        this.rect.x,
        this.rect.y,
        this.rect.w,
        this.rect.h,
      )
    }
  }

  mouseUp = e => {
    this.drag = false
  }
}

let waveform = new Waveform('#waveform')
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="waveform"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue with this code is that when I drag a rectangle over an already existing one, the portion of the existing one will be erased. I understand why it is so, but I want the rectangles **overlap** instead, so that two (or more) can exist at the same time. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution where I removed your clearReact line.

```js
class Waveform {
  constructor(container_selector, logger_selector) {
    this.rects = []
    this.logger = new Logger(logger_selector)
    this.render(container_selector)
  }

  render(container_selector) {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector(container_selector)
    this.canvas.width = 800
    this.canvas.height = 150
    this.canvas.style.border = '1px solid black'
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7)'

    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown)
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove)
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp)
  }

  mouseDown = e => {
    this.drag = true
    this.rect = {}
    this.rect.x = e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft
    this.rect.y = 0
    this.rect.w = 1
    this.rect.h = this.canvas.height
    this.ctx.fillRect(
      this.rect.x,
      this.rect.y,
      this.rect.w,
      this.rect.h,
    )
  }

  mouseMove = e => {
    if (this.drag) {
      this.rect.w = (e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft) - this.rect.x;
      this.ctx.fillRect(
        this.rect.x,
        this.rect.y,
        this.rect.w,
        this.rect.h,
      )
    }
  }

  mouseUp = e => {
    this.drag = false
    this.rects.push(this.rect)
    this.logger.add(this.rect)
  }
  
  getRects() {
    return this.rects
  }
}

class Logger {
  constructor(container_selector) {
    this.list = document.querySelector(container_selector)
  }
  
  add(obj) {
    let li = document.createElement("li")
    li.textContent = JSON.stringify(obj)
    this.list.appendChild(li)
  }
}

let waveform = new Waveform('#waveform', '#list')
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="waveform"></canvas>
</body>

<ul id="list">
</ul>

</html>
```

I suggest you to change fill color for each rect you insert in your canvas.

Comment: Thanks. So the key was to store rects in an array and redraw them on each mouse move.